# Any geometric interpretation for the adjoint system of a linear dynamical system?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, hilbert-spaces, control-theory, linear-control, geometric-interpretation

On page 26, Section 1.3, of his book on linear dynamical systems<sup>[1](https://epubs.siam.org/doi/book/10.1137/1.9781611973884)</sup>, Professor Roger Brockett asks:

---

> [image]

---

> If $$\dot{\mathbf{x}}(t) = A(t) x(t) , \qquad \mathbf{x}(0) = \mathbf{x}_0$$ and $$\dot{\mathbf{p}}(t) = -A^T(t) \mathbf{p}(t), \qquad \mathbf{p}(0) = \mathbf{p}_0 \quad (\mbox{Adjoint System}),
> $$ show that $$ \langle \mathbf{x}(t), \mathbf{p}(t) \rangle = \langle \mathbf{x}_0, \mathbf{p}_0 \rangle \quad\mbox{for all} \ t \in
> \mathbf{R}
> $$

---

**My take**

An easy way to show that a certain function $\psi(t)$ is a constant function is to show that $\dot{\psi}(t) \equiv 0$.

Thus, we find that
$$
{d \over dt} \langle \mathbf{x}(t), \mathbf{p}(t) \rangle \, =  \, \langle \dot{\mathbf{x}}(t), \mathbf{p}(t) \rangle
+ \langle \mathbf{x}(t), \dot{\mathbf{p}}(t) \rangle 
$$
That is,
$$
{d \over dt} \langle \mathbf{x}(t), \mathbf{p}(t) \rangle \, = \, \langle A(t) \mathbf{x}(t), \mathbf{p}(t) \rangle
+  \langle \mathbf{x}(t), - A^T(t) \mathbf{p}(t) \rangle
$$

Simplifying, we get
$$
{d \over dt} \langle \mathbf{x}(t), \mathbf{p}(t) \rangle \, = - \mathbf{x}^T(t) A^T(t)  \mathbf{p}(t) +  \mathbf{x}^T(t) A^T(t)  \mathbf{p}(t) \equiv 0
$$

This shows that
$$
\langle \mathbf{x}(t), \mathbf{p}(t) \rangle = \langle \mathbf{x}_0, \mathbf{p}_0 \rangle \ \ \mbox{for all} \ t \in
\mathbf{R}
$$

I hope that the calculations are correct.

I would like to learn more on the adjoint of a linear dynamical system. Is there any geometric interpretation for the adjoint of a linear dynamical system and the identity established in the Brockett's exercise problem?

---

**References**

1. Roger W. Brockett, [Finite Dimensional Linear Systems](https://epubs.siam.org/doi/book/10.1137/1.9781611973884), Wiley, 1970.

Comment: Why not use bold for matrices, too?

Comment: Prof. Brockett uses the terminology "adjoint equation" for the same system at a later part of his book. His Section 1.7 is devoted to "adjoint equations" and Theorem 1 (Page 44) calls this system as "adjoint equation". I prefer calling it as "adjoint system" and it amounts to the same. I wish to learn more about it, thanks.

Comment: Have you considered taking a damped mass-spring system, finding its $\dot x = A x$ and then studying its adjoint system?

Comment: Thank you. As these are linear systems, I can find explicit solutions of both systems. I shall check with some calculations!

Comment: [This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_mechanics#Example) may be useful (or not).

Comment: I just recalled that I studied about adjoint systems in the optimization problems involving linear control systems for Pontryagin's maximum principle. I got very interested now. I shall read those papers and update myself, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the clearest geometric interpretation of the adjoint system is as the cotangent lift of the original differential equation.

Consider a (time-independent) differential equation $\dot{x} = f(x)$ on a manifold $M$, specified by a vector field $f$ which is a section of the tangent bundle to $M$. This generates a flow $\Phi_{t}$ on $M$; the adjoint system is a differential equation on the cotangent bundle $T^*M$ whose flow is given by the cotangent lift of the flow $\Phi_{t}$; i.e., the flow of the adjoint system is given by $(\Phi_{-t})^*$ where $^*$ denotes the pullback. The vector field on $T^*M$ describing the adjoint system ODE on the cotangent bundle is given by the cotangent lift of the vector field $f$.

In fact, the adjoint system corresponds to a symplectic flow on the cotangent bundle equipped with its canonical symplectic form. To see this, define the Hamiltonian $H(x,p) = \langle p, f(x)\rangle$ where $\langle \cdot,\cdot\rangle$ denotes the duality pairing between $T^*M$ and $TM$. Hamilton's equations for this Hamiltonian is precisely the adjoint system,

$$ \dot{x} = \partial H/\partial p = f(x),\ \dot{p} = -\partial H/\partial x = - (Df(x))^T p$$

For an intrinsic definition of $H$, let $\hat{f}$ be any lift of $f$ to a vector field on the cotangent bundle; then, define $H = i_{\hat{f}}\theta$ where $\theta$ is the tautological one-form on the cotangent bundle, which you can see gives the same coordinate expression as above. This is independent of the choice of lift because $\theta$ is a horizontal one-form with respect to the bundle $T^*M \rightarrow M$. Then, the adjoint system is defined intrinsically as the differential equation corresponding to the Hamiltonian vector field $X_H$ satisfying $i_{X_H} \Omega = dH$, where $\Omega$ is the canonical symplectic form on the cotangent bundle.

In terms of the conservation property you discussed, if $(\Phi_t)_*$ denotes the pushforward of the flow of the original differential equation onto the tangent bundle, then for $v(t) = (\Phi_t)_* v_0$, $v_0 \in T_xM$, and $p(t) = (\Phi_{-t})^*p_0$, $p_0 \in T_x^*M$, we have

$$ \langle p(t), v(t) \rangle = \langle (\Phi_{-t})^*p_0, (\Phi_{t})_*v_0\rangle = \langle p_0, (\Phi_{-t} \circ \Phi_t)_* v_0\rangle = \langle p_0, v_0\rangle.  $$

This property can actually be interpreted as symplecticity of the flow on $T^*M$ (see the linked paper below for details).

In your case, the differential equation you started with is linear, so you can identify $v$ with $x$ and this gives the same relation that you derived (modulo the fact that your equation was time-dependent; you can use the formalism of time-dependent Hamiltonian mechanics to derive an analogous theory, but I stuck to the time-independent case for simplicity).

For more details, you can see the paper [Geometric Methods for Adjoint Systems](https://arxiv.org/abs/2205.02901).

Regarding your comment on the terminology "adjoint system" vs "adjoint equation", the adjoint equation refers to the differential equation for $p$ whereas adjoint system refers to the combined system for $(x, p)$. Note that the adjoint equation is then coordinate-dependent, so either requires a trivial cotangent bundle (e.g. $M$ is a vector space) or a connection to make sense of in a coordinate-independent way. The adjoint system, on the other hand, is a coordinate-independent concept, as explained above (it corresponds to a Hamiltonian system on the cotangent bundle).

Comment: Thanks a lot for great help with details! I will read the paper also!

Comment: No problem. If you have any questions about the paper, feel free to ask.