# Transpose of a linear map given by ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, adjoint-operators, transpose

Consider an ODE
$$
\dot x(t) = A(t) x(t) + B(t) b
$$
$$
x(0) = 0
$$
for $A(t) \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$, $B(t) \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times m}$, $b \in \mathbb{R}^m$

Let's denote by $S(t) : \mathbb{R}^m \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ taking $b$ to $x(t)$. This map is linear thus we can talk about its transpose $S^T(t)$.

**Question:** Is there a nice formula for $S^T(t)y$ where $y\in \mathbb{R}^n$?

---

Attempted solution that does not give satisfactory answer:

Denote $U(t) \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ the solution matrix for the homogenous problem i.e. $\dot U(t) = A(t) U(t)$, $U(0) = I$.

Then $x(t)$ can be expressed as:
$$
x(t) = U(t) \int_0^t U^{-1}(s) B(s) b ds
$$
Thus $S(t)$ is indeed linear map, give by:
$$
S(t) = U(t) \int_0^t U^{-1}(s) B(s) ds
$$
and its transpose is:
$$
S^T(t) = \left( \int_0^t B^T(s) U^{-T}(s) ds \right) U^T(t)
$$

Now for $y_0 \in \mathbb{R}^n$, I want to compute $y(t) = S^T(t)y_0$. Ideally, get an ODE for $y(t)$ and solve it.

By differentiating the expression for $S^T(t)$ we can show that it satisfies this equation:
$$
\dot S^T(t) = B^T(t) + S^T(t) A^T(t)
$$
Unfortunately, we can't conclude that $y(t) = S^T(t)y_0$ satisfies
$$
\dot y(t) = B^T(t)y(t) + A^T(t) y(t)
$$
which is only meaningful if $n=m$, but it is a type of an answer I would like to get i.e. nice ODE for $y(t)$ I can solve.

Comment: Any progress???

Comment: $$
\dot S^T(t) = B^T(t) + S^T(t) A^T(t)
$$ looks correct, at least

Comment: Are you acquainted with the [Controllability Gramian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Controllability_Gramian#Linear_Time_Variant_Systems)?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose we have the following **linear time-varying** (LTV) system

$$ {\dot {\bf x}} (t) = {\bf A} (t) \, {\bf x} (t) + {\bf B} (t) \, {\bf u} (t)$$

with initial state ${\bf x} (t_0) =: {\bf x}_0 = {\bf 0}$. Integrating, we obtain

$$ {\bf x} (t) = \underbrace{{\bf \Phi} (t, t_0) \, {\bf x}_0}_{= {\bf 0}} + \int_{t_0}^t {\bf \Phi} (t, \tau) \, {\bf B} (\tau) \, {\bf u} (\tau) \, {\rm d} \tau $$

where ${\bf \Phi} (t, t_0)$ denotes the [state-transition matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State-transition_matrix) from $t_0$ to $t$. If the input signal is **constant**, i.e., ${\bf u} (t) = {\bar {\bf u}}$, then

$$ {\bf x} (t) = \color{blue}{\left( \int_{t_0}^t {\bf \Phi} (t, \tau) \, {\bf B} (\tau)  \, {\rm d} \tau \right)} {\bar {\bf u}}$$

Note that if $\bf A$ and $\bf B$ were time-invariant, the integrals above would be [convolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution) integrals with matrix exponentials. For details, take a look at section 2.6 of [Antsaklis & Michel](https://doi.org/10.1007/0-8176-4435-0).

Comment: I fail to see how does that answer my question, the state transition matrix $\Phi(t,s)$ is equal to my $U(t)U^{-1}(s)$ and your expression for $x(t)$ is already in my question. I'm looking for some nice expression for $\left( \int_{t_0}^t {\bf \Phi} (t, \tau) \, {\bf B} (\tau)  \, {\rm d} \tau \right)^Ty$

Comment: @tom So, you want a "nice expression" for the "convolution" integral **without** providing information on functions $\bf A$ and $\bf B$.  Good luck!!!   What other miracles would you like to order, my good sir?

Comment: Yeah the question is a bit fuzzy but can't there by an ODE for $y(t)$ that does not involve the state transition matrix? I would consider that a nice expression for $y(t)$

Comment: @tom Have you **ever** seen a state-transition matrix in closed-form?  I do **not** recall ever seeing one, though I probably did see a few for some simple toy problems.

Comment: The expression for $x(t)$ does involve the state transition matrix but ODE for $x(t)$ does not. I'm asking for an ODE for $y(t)$, expecting that it also does not involve the state transition matrix, even though the final expression for $y(t)$ does.

Comment: @tom And what the heck is $\bf y$?  By the way, does the part that I highlighted in blue depend on $\bf x$? No, it depends only on the pair $({\bf A}, {\bf B})$, which defines the LTV system

Comment: What the heck, did you read my question? I define $y(t)$ there.

Comment: @tom Unfortunately, your question is incomprehensible.   What the heck are $S(t) : \mathbb{R}^m \to \mathbb{R}^n$ or $y(t) = S^T(t)y_0$? Is $t \in \mathbb{R}^m$? Is $S$ even square?

Comment: Forget it, I do not see a willingness to help from your side and you just keep on mocking my question from the start. If you asked for clarifications on these things at the start I would be more then happy to explain but now I feel it is just waste of your and my time.

Comment: @tom You asked for a linear map and I gave you one.  You could delete 80% of your question because you are most likely asking for miracles.  And telling you that you are looking for miracles is the best help you could get, though **not** the help you want. Now, instead of complaining about my comments, why don't you improve your question?  Once you have improved your question enough, I can improve my answer as well. Deal?

Comment: @tom Are you perhaps thinking of something like the [adjoint system](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4434856/339790)?

Comment: Yes exactly, something like the adjoint system, but my system is slightly different then in the linked question.

Comment: @tom Then refine your question.